# How do you achieve this soft/glowish low contrast black and white look?

Tags: editing, video-quality, color-correction, color-grading, premiere-pro

Watched La Haine 4k version the other day and was captivated by how BFI gave the film a much low contrast soft look in comparison to criterion hard contrast look. I know lightning plays a vital role but did they add a filter or lower the whites?. It seems as if there is a glowing outline around body figures and objects , in which I wondering if they used a HDR effect?. Has the tool of clarity been used too?. I'm not planning on using any types of mist filters because it will strengthen the highlights too much in which this is something that I don't attend to aim for , due to me editing in post-production

[image: 4k]
[image: criterion]
[image: 4k]
[image: criterion]
[image: 4k]
[image: criterion]